# Add http:// to a link if it doesn't have it

Tags: php, regex

I have this very simple url bbcoder which i wish to adjust so if the linked does not contain http:// to add it in, how can i do this?

```
    $find = array(
    "/\[url\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is",
    "/\[url\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is"
    );

    $replace = array(
    "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>",
    "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>"
    );

    $body = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body);
```

Comment: What if they want to link to a local target? What if they want to do `//example.com/path/to/file.ext` to link while keeping the same scheme?

Comment: It's not meant for local linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `(http://)?` to match the `http://` if exists, and ignore the group result in 'replace to' pattern and use your own `http://` , like this:

```
$find = array(
"/\[url\=(http://)?(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is",
"/\[url\](http://)?(.+?)\[\/url\]/is"
);

$replace = array(
"<a href=\"http://$2\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>",
"<a href=\"http://$2\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>"
);

$body = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body);
```

Comment: Bingo, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Haha, I was editting this in my reply. I used the `?:` indicator for regex, that way you dont need to +1 all groups' variables ($1->$2 etc). Easier to read and needs less memory (because php doesnt need to remember the value of the group)

Comment: Yes, use `(?:` is better, then need not to +1 on group number.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(strpos($string, 'http://') === FALSE) {
    // add http:// to string
}
```

Comment: How would I add this into my code above? Since it may appear multiple times.

Comment: I think the OP was trying to find out how to `add http:// to string`. Your answer doesn't address that part.

Answer (score 3):

```
// I've added the http:// in the regex, to make it optional, but not remember it,
// than always add it in the replace

$find = array(
    "/\[url\=(?:http://)(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is",
    "/\[url\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is"
    );

    $replace = array(
    "<a href=\"http://$1\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>",
    "<a href=\"http://$1\" target=\"_blank\">http://$1</a>"
    );

    $body = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body);
```

---

If you would use a callback function and `preg_replace_callback()`, you can use something like this:
You can do that this way. It will always add 'http://', and than the string without 'http://'

```
$string = 'http://'. str_replace('http://', '', $string);
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know what is faster. `strpos` and the if-clause or `str_replace`. :)

Comment: `strpos()` is faster than `str_replace()`, but the `str_replace()` in the if() might discard that benefit. I prefer this method because I think it's easier to read, and more clear to what it does, early micro-optimising can hurt more than it does good